# How can i add Localizable.strings file?

Tags: ios, localization

How can I add Localizable.strings file? I will try but could not view the string but show only key.

Ex: GOOD_MORNING="Good Morning ";

Result :
         GOOD_MORNING

Comment: The best way to start localization is to follow the apple doc. [Localizing Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html)

Answer (score 6):

First go to project info :
[image]

after pressing the + button choose the other languages you want to add then choose the files you want to localize  like the storyboard and .Xib files in your project and before doning so change all the hard coded strings in your project to 
    NSLocalizedString(@"Good Morning", @"");

and it will create the strings file for you if not just on the project add new file and choose a .strings file after it's created select the file in the project and in the localization pane you will find a localize button press it then select base after this the localization pane for this fill will be like this but with your selected languages

[image]

click on your secondary language and it will create for you another strings file inside the first on that will hold the translated text and fill this file text with this format :

in the english base file :
"Good Morning" = "Good Morning";

in the other language file ex(arabic) : 
"Good Morning"= "صباح الخير";

Hope my answer benefits you